# Android Coverflow Starting Position

Tags: java, android

I am using https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow coverflow widget in my application. The problem that I have is that I am unable to control the starting position of the widget . I am astonished that no body has asked this , or ashamed that maybe they figured this one out themselves.

When I load a list of say 15 elements , the middle image on the screen is the 3rd. If I swipe to left I will find 2 more , and the rest of them will be when seen when I swipe to the right.

I want the middle image to be the 7th element, so that right and left swipes reveal same number of items.

Aid me please ?

Comment: hi, im using it too. please add your code and your adapter and i will try helping you.

Comment: @SacreDeveloper ty for the shoulder. But my code is the same as posted on the link that I gave . I am using that exact widget , and the test code is also provided .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your coverFlow selection to 0 in CoverFlowExampleActivity , like this:

```
coverFlow.setSelection(4, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I could be this lazy/stupid. I can't accept your answer as yet .

Answer (score 0):

You can set your coverFlow scrollToPosition to 7 in CoverFlowExampleActivity , like this:

```
coverFlow.scrollToPosition(7);
```

Comment: This is the correct method to bring the selected item to top or front of the Coverflow. Thank You